# Why magento is so slow

Tags: magento2.1.5

I just install mangento CE 2.1.5 in my laptop. I use XAMPPto host mangeto. My laptop is i7 processor, 8G RAM. I host other websites and visit them, is fast. Howover, when I visit my mangeto website, it let me feel this website is slow. Why? because a lot of images to load? How to solve performance issue?

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways to optimize your website.

- Use flat catalog model
- Minify js and css
- Optimize the images
- Use gzip compression in .htaccess file, etc.

You can use an online tool to analyse your website. For example - https://gtmetrix.com/

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 is slow when cache is disabled and it is in developer mode. You can do below two steps to make it faster

- Enable cache from admin (System > Cache Management) if disabled.
- Execute command at root of your Magento 2 installation to move it to production mode.

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

Comment: 'php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production'
What is this using for? I need this command even though I set it in admin panel?
Where do I put this command? Using what tool to enter this command?

Comment: This command will set magento 2 to production mode and you can execute it by using terminal if you are using mac or Linux. But if you are using windows then it can be done using cmd.